# c/objective-c question

Tags: iphone, c, compilation

I am truing to use a c function in a .c file from within my objective-c class.
I have imported the header for the c file. but I am still getting a problem and my program would not compile.

Undefined symbols:

"gluUnProject(float, float, float, float const*, float const*, int const*, float*, float*, float*)", referenced from:
      -[GLView checkCollission:object:] in GLView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea how I can resolve this issue ?
Any help is certainly appreciated. 
Qutaibah

Comment: Just checking, you using gluUnProject that you wrote yourself in your iphone project? iPhone does not ship with glu by default. See http://code.google.com/p/iphone-glu/

Answer (score 3):

This error is posted by the linker and not the compiler. Often this is caused by the code being compiled as C and included from C++ or the other way around.

You can normally fix this by ensuring that the function definitions in the header file enforces any C++ compiler to use C syntax by adding the following to the header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... definitions goes here ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This method also ensures that the .c file itself is treating the function definitions as C and not by accident get compiled as C++.

If you do not wish to alter the header, you can encapsulate the #include statement in the same way. This will however not ensure correct compilation of the .c file itself.

EDIT:
Just a thought: I presume that you are actually compiling the .c file?

Comment: Thanks Claus, In xCode, I right click on 'glu.c' and hit compile. 
in the header for the glu.c file: 

#ifndef _GLU_H_
#define _GLU_H_
#endif

Comment: Have you actually added the glu.c file to your project, so it is part of the build?

Comment: Yes, It shows up in the groups & files pane. 
BTW, I was able to make it work following the points you have provided in your answer above. thank you very much.